# Why is req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('page') returning null instead of the value from the query params in url in the deployed Nextjs 13.4.19 app

Tags: next.js13

I have a url `http://mysite/api/records?sort=Newest&page=1`.

For some reason using

```
const sort = req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('sort');
```

returns null instead of the the value Newest.

This occurs only in the deployed app and not localhost.
I am currently using Nextjs 13.4.19

```
import {NextResponse, NextRequest} from 'next/server';

const GET = (async (req: NextRequest) => {

  if (!req || !req.nextUrl) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: 'Invalid Request'}, {status: 400});
  }

  const sort = req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('sort');
  const page = req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('page');

  console.log(req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('sort'), typeof req?.nextUrl?.searchParams?.get('sort'));

  try {

    return NextResponse.json({
      sort,
      page,
    });

  } catch (error: any) {
    let message;
    if (error.message === 'fetch failed') {
      message = 'Session Timeout';
    } else {
      message = error.message;
    }
    return NextResponse.json({error: message}, {status: 500});
  }

});

export {GET};
```

Comment: Please debug this further. Check what the URL is for example.

Comment: can you show the result of `console.log(req?.nextUrl?.searchParams)`

Comment: the issue was resolved... the issue was caused due to cdn caching the headers... the code itself wasnt the issue